# how to open multiple consoleview with different input text

Tags: eclipse-rcp

i want to  open multiple console view with different input text on single swt button click in eclipse rcp application
Can anybody tell me about this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add org.eclipse.ui.console as dependency and after that you can create different extensions.
Some more details about the implementation you can find on this page http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t66777.html.

Here a simple implementation ([source](http://de.comp.lang.java.narkive.com/gKY9USRE/eclipse-osgi-implementierung-konsolen-zugriff)):

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories">
        <consoleFactory label="ConsoleX" class="console.Factory">
        </consoleFactory>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

**class Factory**

```
package console;

import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;

public class Factory implements IConsoleFactory {

    private static MessageConsole _console;

    public void openConsole() {
        MessageConsole console = getConsole();
        if (console != null) {
            IConsoleManager manager =
            ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager();
            IConsole[] existing = manager.getConsoles();
            boolean exists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++) {
                if(console == existing[i])
                    exists = true;
            }
            if(! exists)
                manager.addConsoles(new IConsole[] {console});
            manager.showConsoleView(console);
        }

    }

    public static MessageConsole getConsole() {
        if (_console == null) {
            _console = new MessageConsole("ConsoleX",null);
        }
        return _console;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
Factory.getConsole().activate();
Factory.getConsole().newOutputStream().write("Hello world.".getBytes());
```

Comment: If something helps you, don't forget to vote up and similar. :)