# show console in runtime eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console

I'm developing an eclipse plugin. It uses a type of grammar to process texts. The grammar can be composed and compiled. I have an existing tool that compiles the grammar. This tool displays errors in console if the grammar has any.

When I run my eclipse plugin, a new eclipse instance opens. If I load a grammar and compile it in my new eclipse instance, the error are still printed to the old eclipse. Is there any way to redirect the message from old eclipse to the new eclipse instance?

Comment: [FAQ How do I write to the console from a plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F)

Comment: I can write to console. My problem is: a module which I use write messages to the console in the eclipse which I use to run the new eclipse instance. And I want to redirect those messages to the console in my new eclipse instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html) ?

I think using -console or -debug might be your solution (it display a second windows at eclipse startup showing sysout)

Comment: thanks for the hint but clearly this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories` extension point to create your own console to go into the Console View. The answer on the following question shows an example extension point and factory class along with an example of how to write to the console:

[how to open multiple consoleview with different input text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10580516/1257372)

Answer (score 0):

[greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) provided you with the answer to your question, his [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F) tells you how to implement a console inside your new Eclipse instance.

I think that confusion arose because of the **old console** (the Eclipse console in your development environment) and the **new console** (the console in the new Eclipse instance).

The code in the article provided covers how to create a console and write to this console *inside your new instance*.

If you don't find that useful, then [this article](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2006/10/19/displaying-the-console-in-your-rcp-application/) also covers how to create a console for your plugin.

It is also useful to mention that when you're developing a plugin for Eclipse, you're using the Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP), and if you search for this when looking for help (like I did when I was trying to develop a plugin), I'm sure you'll find a lot more.